# Memory leak in SQLite for C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using sqlite in C#. To test the performance when the size of database goes large, I write a program to generate random data, which ran out of memory.
I found I have created a new IDbCommand instance by

```
IDbCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand() ;
```

method for every new insert, and that's where the memory leaks. And if I call `

```
cmd.Dispose();`
```

after executing the SQLCommand, everything is OK.
Usually, there won't be large number of operations, so I don't mind the time lose of creating new Command instance for every operation. But if the memory won't be disposed, that's a problem.

Is that my duty to call cmd.Dispose() or it's a bug of sqlite-net?

Comment: Why not using a prepared parametrized command and use it in the loop? That would be way more efficient.

Comment: Even through I use a prepared command, I still have to create new command for every upper-level instance. I want to know if there's risk of memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to dispose everything that implements `IDisposable`.

You could use the `using` statement to do this:

```
using (IDbCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Please note that `cmd` goes out of scope outside of the `using` statement block. The `using` statement disposes your `IDisposable` when executes goes out of that block. It also disposes everything in case of an exception.

Comment: What if I have a class that has a member of command instance?It seems the Connection implements IDisposable too. Where the best place to dispose them?

Comment: Generally, you should dispose objects as soon as you're done with it. So dispose of it when you're finished using it. Not sure what you asking about having a member of `IDbCommand` type. You just declare it normally and wrap the initialization in the `using` statement. When it goes out of scope, it's umanaged resources are released and disposed, meaning it doesn't reference the command you created. Using it after a using block but without initializing it again will throw an exception.

Comment: For example, I have a class which have an IDbCommand member variable. To increase the efficiency, I prepared it in the constructor, as @Tarik said. When the instance of the class is no longer used, I think I should dispose the command. Should I implements IDisposable and Dispose the command, or if I can dispose it in Finalize method? I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Implement `IDisposable` and dispose of your object in managed code. You should **also** call the `Dispose()` method in the class destructor, the only difference is that you're passing false as a parameter.