# Program Memory allotted to the application (32MB) getting filled and Handheld got rebooted.

Tags: .net, mobile, compact-framework, honeywell

Posted on MS forumMobile Worker module Insights

Technology Stack:
Software:Visual Studio 2008, .NET Framework 3.5, Windows Mobile 6.5.3, SQLite Database, RESCO UI controls

Hardware:Honeywell Dolphin 99EX device
Processor: Texas Instruments® OMAP3715 1.0GHz processor
Operating System: Microsoft® Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Professional and Classic
Memory: 512 MB RAM x 1 GB Flash

Problem domain:  When we run the application on handheld device, the Program Memory allotted to the application (32MB) getting filled and Handheld got rebooted.  There is no provision to increase the Program memory (Virtual memory) for this model device.

- Mobile worker application start working with approximately 12-14 MB virtually memory remaining on the device.
- Rest is utilized in Application launch and other startup processes.
- As users proceed with their task (opening forms), virtually memory starts decreasing gradually at each task by avg of .20 MB. We are closing the forms when the task is completed on that page.However, between there are few process that consumes 1 MB memory during data collation binding or during select process from SQL lite.
- Virtual memory remain at 5MB if users stay on the same flow or working on the same forms. However, it start decreasing beyond 5MB if users leave the current flow and enter in the new flow that required new forms to open.
- From here onwards as worker opens a new process memory decreases and come down to zero. This causes the application to crash and reboot.

Below is the memory logs when we start the device. 300 remaining out of 400 physical memory and 24 MB remaining out of 32 MB of virtual memory

- Memory status at the successful launch of the Application:-
  300.79/420.94 (MB)Phys, 24.44 /32.00 (MB)Virtual
- Memory status after SQL lite table creation that triggers automatically after successful ECD application launch 
  290.45/420.94 (MB)Phys, 16.25 /32.00 (MB)Virtual
- Memory status after New HH register process, As the device was, register device process ran and consumed approximately 2 MB:- 
  288.60/420.94 (MB)Phys, 14.50 /32.00 (MB)Virtual
- Memory status after supervisor login:-
  281.88/420.94 (MB)Phys, 12.06 /32.00 (MB)Virtual
- Supervisor started performing different action and memory utilization gradually started going up and gradually came down to zero:-
  Memory status after Dock view collection bind. 
  271.11/420.94 (MB) Phys, 9.00 /32.00 (MB) Virtual.

---

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory leak in the code.

To free up memory used by forms do Dispose and then set to null and then GC.Collect to force memory garbage collection. Do that with other objects too after they are disposed explicitely by code.

You can free up memory by moving code into a .NET library. Dot Net libraries are not loaded into the process slot memory (32MB minus DLLs) completely starting with Windows Mobile 6.5 (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robtiffany/2009/04/09/memmaker-for-the-net-compact-framework/).

If the memory leak is inside a DotNet object, you can use Remote Performance Monitor (ie see here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevenpr/2007/03/08/finding-managed-memory-leaks-using-the-net-cf-remote-performance-monitor/ and http://gruffcode.com/2012/12/27/finding-memory-leaks-in-net-compact-framework-applications/

If the memory leak is in a native library, you need to check the code for missing free() statements or objects that are allocated but not freed after usage (ie Fonts, Bitmaps, Brushes etc.).

Comment: Dear Josef, this is what we  thought. We are still not able to find out exact leak . May be Resco Mobile forms Control images are never disposed or Xzing.net bar code reader leaks or SqLite is the issue.

Comment: Yes, try Performance Monitor to find the leak or do periodic or defined (on object creation and after dispose) memory logs to a file to see which component is the root cause. A process memory usage will not help, as you need to find the object or code sequence that does not free memory. As you are using Resco and other third party controls/objects, you can not easily switch to alternative objects with same function.

Comment: The other issue may simply be that your app is usng too much resources for a limitted OS like Windows Mobile 6.5. Try the memmaker advise to move code to a library or change the program to use less resouces. Or use separate processes and IPC to split the huge application into smaller parts. One process get's one 32MB slot (minus DLLs), two processes will get two slots and so one.

Comment: We have tried moving logic to DLL, however we get error - The buffer manager failed to allocate a buffer of 2220732 byte. Please help us.

Comment: Dear Josef, could you please review?

Comment: Dear Joseph - Memory usage increased when tables are created in SQlite. We are using version 1.0.96.0v. Please suggest

Comment: Analyze further and post a bug report at SQLite. Possibly this may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190171/memory-leak-in-sqlite-for-c